# ExtJS 3.4 : How to change fieldset size dynamically

Tags: extjs, dynamic, extjs3, fieldset

I am trying to add an item into a `fielset` dynamically. I have checked the  items of the fieldset in the console , the item is being added to the fieldset but it is not being displayed, I am invoking the `doLayout()` method for the fieldset and also for the `formpanel` which has this fieldset, but the size/height of the fieldset does not change. Can someone help me with this issue?

```
 if(csType.value=="OS"){
            Ext.apply(newOs,that.osCombo);
            newOs.id = 'testOs2';
            Ext.getCmp('cSFieldSet').add(newOs);
            Ext.getCmp('cSFieldSet').setHeight(600);
            Ext.getCmp('cSFieldSet').doLayout(true,true);
            Ext.getCmp('cSFieldSet').ownerCt.doLayout(true,true);
            that.csFormPanel.doLayout(true,true);
        }
```

I also tried using `autoHeight: true`,  but still the item is not being displayed

Comment: can you post your formpanel code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some test code I just wrote to simulate what you are trying to achieve:

```
var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
            labelWidth: 75, 
            frame:true,
            title: 'Simple Form',
            bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
            width: 350,
            defaults: {width: 230},
            defaultType: 'textfield',

            items: [{
                // Fieldset in Column 1
                xtype:'fieldset',
                itemId: 'fieldSetTest',
                columnWidth: 0.5,
                title: 'Fieldset 1',
                collapsible: false,
                autoHeight:false,
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items :[{
                        fieldLabel: 'Field 1'
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Field 2'
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Field 3'
                    }
                ]
            }
            ],

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Add New Field',
                handler: function() {
                    var newItem = new Ext.form.TextField({fieldLabel: 'New Fields'});
                    simple.getComponent('fieldSetTest').add(newItem);
                    simple.doLayout();
                },
                scope:this
            }]
        });

        simple.render(document.body);

    });
```

This works fine, so on clicking the add button the new item appears in the fieldset and the height of the fieldset automatically increases. Without seeing your whole formpanel code I can't comment much further.

Comment: Thanks..that worked perfectly,. but how to remove a component? I tried something like this `simple.getComponent('fieldSetTest').remove(newItem);` and it din work

Comment: @Shruti try `fieldset.remove(Ext.getCmp('componentIdToRemove'))` Not sure of `Ext.getCmp` exists in 3.4, but use whatever allows you to get a handle on an ExtJS component.

Comment: If you set itemId on each of the fieldset items you can do fieldset.remove(fieldset.getComponent('itemIdhere')). You could probably even do fieldset.getComponent('itemIdHere').destroy()